# Access values from dictionary that stores values in parent class attributes

Tags: python

Two Classes Country and City. City inherits from country class and it also calls the init from country class to store values

```
class Country:
    def __init__(self, Name, Population):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Population = Population

def get_Name(self):
    print(self.Name)

def get_population(self):
    return self.Population


class City(Country):
    def __init__(self, cityName, Citypopulation, Country, CountryPopulation):
        self.cityName = cityName
        self.Citypopulation = Citypopulation 
        Country.__init__(Country, CountryPopulation)
```

Main includes:

```
Cities = {
    "Japan" : City("Tokyo", "13.6M", "Japan", "125.8M"),
    "England": City("London", "9M", "England", "55.98M"),
    "US": City("New York", "8.3M", "US", "329.5M")
}

for x in Cities:
    print(Cities[x].cityName)
```

How can i access the Countrypopulation/CountryName like I did for cityName.
Something like

```
for x in Cities:
    print(Cities[x].Countrypopulation)
```

I'm fairly new to python...

Comment: You are using Country `__init__` attributes will be named as defined there, aka `Name` and `Population` - `Cities[x].Name`

Comment: it say City object has no attribute Name

Comment: Replace `Country.__init__(Country, CountryPopulation)` in `City` `__init__` with `super().__init__(Country, CountryPopulation)` then access value with `Cities[x].Name`

Comment: BTW, the structure is wrong. If you subclass `City` from `Country` you basically say that a city is a country and that is wrong. A city belongs to a country (or more countries e.g. Jerusalem).

Comment: If you're a beginner you might be interested in the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). Use camel case names for classes but lowercase with underscore for variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna say your structure doesn't make sense currently from the Object Oriented Programming point of view. Inheritance means one class is a subtype of another - is City a Country? Of course not. What you should do is make a country attribute for the city that stores a Country object.

```
class Country:
    def __init__(self, name, population):
        self.name = name
        self.population = population

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def getPopulation(self):
        return self.population


class City():
    def __init__(self, cityName, cityPopulation, country):
        self.cityName = cityName
        self.cityPopulation = cityPopulation 
        self.country = country

japan = Country("Japan", "125.8M")
england = Country("England", "55.98M")
us = Country("US", "329.5M")

tokyo = City("Tokyo", "13.6M", japan)
london = City("London", "9M", england)
ny = City("New York", "8.3M", us)

cities = [tokyo, london, ny]

for city in cities:
    print(city.country.name)
    print(city.cityName)
```

Comment: You might want to fix the wrong indentation of the methods `getName` and `getPopulation`.

Comment: Tbh I'd just ditch those methods altogether. Fixed tho.

Answer (score 0):

The `Country` parameter conflicts with the class `Country`.

You can also use `super()` like this:

```py
class Country:
    def __init__(self, Name, Population):
        self.Name = Name
        self.Population = Population

    def get_Name(self):
        print(self.Name)

    def get_population(self):
        return self.Population


class City(Country):
    def __init__(self, cityName, Citypopulation, Country_, CountryPopulation):
        self.cityName = cityName
        self.Citypopulation = Citypopulation 
        #Country.__init__(self, Country_, CountryPopulation)
        super().__init__(Country_, CountryPopulation)

Cities = {
    "Japan" : City("Tokyo", "13.6M", "Japan", "125.8M"),
    "England": City("London", "9M", "England", "55.98M"),
    "US": City("New York", "8.3M", "US", "329.5M")
}

for x in Cities:
    print(Cities[x].Name)
```

Output:

```
Japan
England
US
```

Also note that making `City` inherit from `Country` doesn't make sense. A City is not a Country. Perhaps you should make each `City` refer to its `Country`.